# can not read object property in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to hide the left / right navigation text by listening to object & its properties.

working example : http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/9EyEu/29/

But, getting following error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hide' of undefined "

```
if(!scroller) { var scroller = {}; }

            scroller = {
                next : "#leftControl",
                prev : "#rightControl",
                videos : {
                    hideButtons : function() {
                        var obj = this;
                        obj.next.hide();
                        obj.prev.hide();
                    },
                    init : function() {
                        var obj =  this;
                        obj.hideButtons();
                    }
                },
                init : function() {
                    var obj =  this;
                    obj.videos.init(); 
                }                            
            }

scroller.init();​
```

Comment: the line `if(!scroller) { var scroller = {}; }` is useless in the context of your code sample above.

Comment: @epascarello you are correct. Actually, i have started working on a plugin using advanced javascript concepts so this statement will come in use later in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the corrected js to the issue:

```
var scroller = {
    next : "#leftControl",
    prev : "#rightControl",
    videos : {
        hideButtons : function() {
            $(scroller.next).hide();
            $(scroller.prev).hide();
        },
        init : function() {
            this.hideButtons();
        }
    },
    init : function() {
        scroller.videos.init(); 
    }                            
};

scroller.init();​
```

As you see, I reference the `scroller` object instead of the `this`.  In the cases where you were setting `var obj = this` the `this` keyword was not referencing the `scroller` object.

Answer (score 2):

@Lokesh your JavaScript error was because `next` and `prev` are strings and they don't have the `hide` method.

Comment: how can i correct the code if the want to apply the hide() method?

Comment: See @john-kalberer's answer.  Also, it would be good if you can explain your requirement so that myself or someone can help with the API.

Comment: actually, i need to create a video thumbnail slider where on every click 3 items will scroll. For this assignment, i have to use advanced javascript concepts to make it configurable. I was in doubt on how object communicates so asked this question. something like this where i used generic javascript : http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/9EyEu/

Comment: @Lokesh you can take a look at the Carousel plugin

Comment: you are right, but my assignment is to develop similar utility from scratch. as you can see in above mentioned example, code is running fine there but need to implement modular javascript approach using namespacing & other advanced javascript concepts.

Comment: @Lokesh what you have is a Singleton, there is no namespace or even a class. Take a look at this for the module pattern which is a better way since you can have private/helper variables and methods <http://yuiblog.com/assets/pdf/crockford-good-parts-ch-5.pdf>.